# Programmatically add a span tag, not a Label control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, code-behind

How can I add a `span` tag from a code behind? Is there an equivalent HtmlControl? I am currently doing it this way. I am building out rows to a table in an Itemplate implementation.

```
var headerCell = new TableHeaderCell { Width = Unit.Percentage(16)};
var span = new LiteralControl("<span class='nonExpense'>From<br/>Date</span>");
headerCell.Controls.Add(span);
headerRow.Cells.Add(headerCell);
```

I know I could use `new Label()`, but I am trying to avoid a server control here. Am I correct in using the `LiteralControl` this way? Does anyone have any better ideas of how to do this?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

With HtmlGenericControl you can create a span dynamically like that :

```
var span = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
span.InnerHtml = "From<br/>Date";
span.Attributes["class"] = "nonExpense";
headerCell.Controls.Add(span);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Label span = new Label();
span.Text = "From<br/>Date";
span.CssClass = "nonExpense";
headerCell.Controls.Add(span);
```

Or, alternatively:

```
Label span = new Label {Text = "From<br/>Date", CssClass = "nonExpense"};
headerCell.Controls.Add(span);
```

Comment: Isn't this going to create a `label` tag?

Answer (score 2):

```
new HtmlGenericControl("span")
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the idea that our friend Canavar said.

Look under System.Web.UI.HtmlControls namespace and you will see a whole bunch of HTML controls that have been mapped to objects, if you can use those.
HtmlGenericControl fits in to any controls that are not defined in .NET and SPAN is a exemple of that.

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late but I wanted to provide my solution for this issue.

```
public class HtmlSpan: HtmlGenericControl
{
  public HtmlSpan(): base("span") { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use literalcontrol. you can add whatever html content you want.
I dont recommend label. (for more information search -label vs literal-.)